# What is happening with my types, TypeError? (Python)

Tags: python

I have a method where I retrieve data from an SQLite database. The data is saved as text (for some reason), but really it float numbers (14.5 etc). This is my method to get them:

```
def retrieveSpeeds(databasepath, someid):
     con = lite.connect(databasepath)
     with con:
        cur = con.execute("SELECT speed FROM speeds WHERE id = someid")
        speeds = [x[0] for x in cur]
        return speeds
```

This returns the following:

```
[u'14.00', u'14.50', u'14.50', u'14.50', u'14.50', u'13.80']
```

However, since I want plain numbers I do:

```
for i in range(0, len(speed)):
     newspeeds.append(float(speed[i]))
```

So now the new return looks like:

```
[14.0, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 13.8]
```

So in my main I do:

```
maxspeeds = []
for id in userid:
    speed = retrieveSpeeds(databasepath, id)
    if len(speed>0):
           maxspeeds.append(max(speed))
for i in range(0,len(maxspeeds)):
    if maxspeeds[i] > 40:
          maxspeeds = maxspeeds.pop(i)
```

This gives me the following TypeError:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    if len(speed>0):
    TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Bool? I 'm extremely confused why my returned list is now a bool.

Comment: You shouldn't use `range` and `len` to iterate. Just do as you did originally with the list comprehension: `speeds = [float(x[0]) for x in cur]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says you wrote `if len(speed>0):` (Note the `>0` inside the `len`), instead of `len(speed)>0`, as you should have written it (and as you did in your code snippet).

Answer (score 1):

Look, you had a typo, the correct way is to do `if len(speed)>0:`. You've corrected it yourself.

`len(5>2)` won't work either as `5>2` returns `True` and `True` has no `len()`