# Why do I get a type error: float when I try to iterate my list

Tags: python

So I sorted out my slightly embarrassing blunder here: [What is happening with my types, TypeError? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679758/what-is-happening-with-my-types-typeerror-python)

Now I got an other one.

My method for retrieving data:

```
def retrieveSpeeds(databasepath, someid):
     con = lite.connect(databasepath)
     with con:
        cur = con.execute("SELECT speed FROM speeds WHERE id = someid")
        speeds = [x[0] for x in cur]
        for i in range(0, len(speed)):
            newspeeds.append(float(speed[i]))
     return speeds
```

So the return looks like:

```
[14.0, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 13.8]
```

In my main I do:

```
maxspeeds = []
for id in userid:
    speed = retrieveSpeeds(databasepath, id)
    if len(speed)>0:
           maxspeeds.append(max(speed))
for i in range(0,len(maxspeeds)):
    if maxspeeds[i] > 40:
          maxspeeds = maxspeeds.pop(i)
```

Now my new problem is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    if maxspeeds[i]>40:
    TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How is it that it suddenly thinks that my list is a float object? More blunders from me?

Comment: Aside from the answers, which are correct, if you are just trying to remove any values over 40 then you can use a list comprehension:  `maxspeeds = [x for x in maxspeeds if x < 40]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning `maxspeeds` to the output of `maxspeeds.pop(i)` which returns a **number**, which is the index of the `pop`ped item. Instead, don't assign anything to the output:

```
maxspeeds = []
for id in userid:
    speed = retrieveSpeeds(databasepath, id)
    if len(speed)>0:
           maxspeeds.append(max(speed))
for i in range(0,len(maxspeeds)):
    if maxspeeds[i] > 40:
          maxspeeds.pop(i) #Here
```

[**`.pop`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) returns the index of the deleted item, so when you assign the list to that output, the list becomes the index (an integer).

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
maxspeeds = maxspeeds.pop(i)
```

rebinds `maxspeeds` to the value of the expression `maxspeeds.pop(i)`, which is a float.